# My ajax JSON object is recognized as "Undefined"

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am having troubles with my ajax call. When I try to alert the result it keeps resulting as Undefined.

Both alerts are resulting to undefined.
I am not too sure if I am coding this correctly, please help me if I am.

Q: If I am accessing it incorrectly, how exactly would I access the skill property/index.

**JQUERY/JSCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Skill sort on change
    $('#order_by').on('change', function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "sort_skill_be.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {skill:this.value}  
        }).done(function(result){
                alert(result[0].skill);
        })
    });
});
```

**PHP FILE: This method receives a statement and places an "object" array to an overall array.**

```
function helpFetchPostInfo($stmt){
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
    $recent_posts = array();
    foreach ($results as $row){
        $post = array(
            'username' => $row['username'],
            'steam' => $row['steam'],
            'skill' => $row['skill'],
            'description' => $row['description'],
            'date' => $row['date'],
        );
        array_push($recent_posts, $post);
    }
    return json_encode($recent_posts);
}
```

Thank you for the assistance it is much appreciated

```
function sortSkill($skill){
    // If All skill is selected display posts normally
    if ($skill == 'All'){
        displayPosts();
        exit;
    }
    $db = connect();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users LEFT JOIN posts 
            ON users.idUsers = posts.fkuser 
            WHERE posts.fkuser IS NOT NULL and users.skill=:skill
            ORDER BY date DESC";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array(':skill' => $skill));      
    if ($stmt->rowCount() == 0){
        // Nothing has returned
        unset($_SESSION['recent_posts']); // Reset session of posts if no posts appear.
    } 
    else
    {
        $recent_posts = helpFetchPostInfo($stmt);
        return $recent_posts;
    }
}
```

Sort skill is being called in a seperate php file called sort_skill_be.php, which is called from the jquery when a selection is changed.

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'database.php';
$skill_sort = $_POST['skill'];
sortSkill($skill_sort);
header('Location:index.php'); 
?>
```

EDIT: added JSON datatype to jquery

Now my problem is the alert is not being called at all anymore.

Comment: Show the code where `helpFetchPostInfo` is called

Comment: Okay, so now show us where `sortSkill` is called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are not providing the `dataType` attribute in your `ajax` method.

```
dataType: "json",
```

Either do that or **parse your result** to `JSON` before accessing it.

I don't see any issue the way you are trying to access the object.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I made that change, and now I am not getting any alert at all anymore. hmmm, Also sorry I am still kind of new with this ajax, what do you mean parse your result to JSON?

Comment: Check your console for any errors.. `Parse` means converting the response to a JSON string

Comment: How exactly do I convert my string to a JSON string?

Comment: `dataType:"json"` takes care of that.. Also try adding a error method and see if it hits that

Comment: Oh okay! thanks. Now my problem is not it is not getting to the alert anyore.

Comment: Which is the correct way of adding an error method, I checked online and I saw one way is by using error : function(){check}?

Comment: THat should do.. just place an alert and see if you hit it

Comment: Pass in a argument to the error function and log it.. Then check your console

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32114/discussion-between-austin-truong-and-sushanth)